# How to ignore files with a certain value in them with pandas

Tags: python, pandas

I am using the following code to read files in a certain directory:

```
import glob
path = r'C:\Users\Lucas\Documents\Thesis\Python\PVdata'                    
all_files = glob.glob(os.path.join(path, "*.csv"))    

df_from_each_file = (pd.read_csv(f, usecols = [0,1,2,3,4,5], sep = '\t', encoding = 'UTF-16') for f in all_files)
df             = pd.concat(df_from_each_file)
```

This works, but I want to ignore files that have "-" values in them, as they are not useful for me. How can this be done?

Comment: Is there a certain column which has values `-` and you want to exclude these? Or it can be present anywhere in the file?

Comment: The first column is the column for the date and time, in all the other columns I don't want a "-" to be present, and if it is, that this whole file is ignored.